# to give options to "if you do not mind <much?>"

Tags: expressions

Can I tell "if you do not mind ?much?"?
Or how can I leave me with some freedom in taking and changing a decision?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"If you don't mind" would be a better alternative.   "Much" would be implied and if you said it, it would feel weird.

Something like:
"If you don't mind, I'd like to change the channel."
or
"I'll just pick somewhere for us to go tonight for dinner, if you don't mind?"

Comment: I tend to find the use of "If you don't mind ''all that much''" is mostly ironic...

Answer (score 1):

"If you don't mind much" would be kind of arrogant, because that indicates that you will still do it if "you actually mind a little". "If you don't mind" would mean more in the line of "if you don't mind at all".